# ejs file loaded but nothing appears

Tags: node.js, express, include, ejs

I'm using NodeJS, expressJS and ejs to load files. while rendering index.ejs `app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.render('index');`, it loaded perfectly but when I'm embedding navbar.ejs in index.ejs `<% include(includes/navbar.ejs) %>` it is loading fine (no error in console) but nothing is appearing on the page. 
**Folder managed:** 

project>app.js , 

project>pages>index.ejs , 

project>pages>includes>navbar.ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a typo there in your syntax. You're missing the `-` in the include. It should rather be

```
<%- include('includes/navbar.ejs'); %>
```

Also note that the path should be in quotes.